# Hive: Joining tables

Tags: sql, hive

I have just started learning SQL and Hive. While trying to complete on of the task facing an issue.

There are  two tables:

```
db_base.memberdata tb_1     
tb_1.mem_id,
tb_1.mem_nbr,
tb_1.mem_grp,
tb_1.mem_ctry,
tb_1.mem_email, 
tb_1.mem_enrldate



db_history.memberhdata tb_2 
tb_2.mem_id,
tb_2.mem_nbr,
tb_2.mem_grp,
tb_2.mem_stat,
tb_2.mem_cd,
tb_2.mem_lvl,
tb_2.mem__stat_desc,
tb_2.mem_enrldate
```

Trying to join the tables via:

```
SELECT tb_1.mem_id,tb_1.mem_nbr,tb_1.mem_grp,tb_1.mem_ctry,tb_1.mem_email,tb_1.mem_enrldate      FROM db_base.memberdata tb_1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
tb_2.mem_id,tb_2.mem_nbr,tb_2.mem_grp,tb_2.mem_stat,tb_2.mem_cd,tb_2.mem_lvl,tb_2.mem__stat_desc,
tb_2.mem_enrldate
FROM db_history.memberhdata tb_2 
WHERE 
tb_2.mem_enrldate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-01' 
AND tb_2.mem_id = 4 AND tb_2.mem_nbr = 1 
AND tb_2.mem_grp = 1) tb_2a
ON tb_2a.mem_id = tb_1.mem_id 
limit 100;
```

Error I am getting is:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 9:0 cannot recognize input near 'ON' 'tb_2' '.' in subquery source
```

Tried looking at couple of examples online but nothing seems to be working here. Sorry for my limited knowledge. Any help please.

After doing an update in the query getting:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 13:9 Invalid column reference 'mem_id'
```

Comment: FROM db_history.memberhdata tb_2     is defined inside of the Parens.  You need to add an alias after the right paren, say tb_2a and then use that alias

Comment: @donPablo Thanks. I did the same as suggested by you but now getting a different error. I have updated it in the main question above.

Comment: I dunno... I do not have the line numbers so I am guessing what is line 13 -- do we need  ) AS tb_2a      -- or can you try to "double qualify?" the ON tb_2a.tb_2.mem_id = tb_1.tb_1.mem_id

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are selecting all from each table, so I am just making it short for simplicity  sake (by using *)

```
SELECT * FROM tb_1 as AA
INNER JOIN
(
select * from tb_2 as Tb_2
WHERE
Tb_2.enrldate between  months_between('2018-06-01', '2015-01-01')
AND Tb_2.id=4 AND Tb_2.nbr=1
AND tb_2.grp=1
) as BB
ON AA.id=BB.id
LIMIT 100;
```

Notice the positions of the aliases AA and BB.